# Automated Tests Fail on App Service Using Custom Repository That Calls SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I created a custom repository per https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Using-Stored-Procedures,-User-Defined-Functions-and-Views/index.html for my asp.net zero project.  Everything works great when I test with the Swagger API test application and from my angular client.  I then tried to write automated tests for the API using asp.net zero testing framework I get
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (The CommandType 'StoredProcedure' is invalid.)
---- System.ArgumentException : The CommandType 'StoredProcedure' is invalid."

It seems like the testing framework is using SQLLite for the DB Context.  I am not sure how to work around this.

TEST THAT IS FAILING

```
    [Fact]
    public void Should_Get_All_StaticItems()
    {
        LoginAsTenant("Default", "admin");
        //Act
        **var types = _ptStaticDataTypeAppService.Get(new PTGetPTStaticDataTypeInput());**

        //Assert
        types.Result.Count.ShouldBe(_totalItems);
    }
```

APP SERVICE METHOD

```
[AbpAuthorize(AppPermissions.Pages_Administration_PT_StaticDataType)]
public class PTStaticDataTypeAppService : PieceTrackerAppServiceBase, IPTStaticDataTypeAppService
{
    IPTStaticDataTypeRepository _ptStaticDataRepository;
    public PTStaticDataTypeAppService(IPTStaticDataTypeRepository ptStaticDataTypeRepository) 
    {
        _ptStaticDataRepository = ptStaticDataTypeRepository;
    }

    public async Task<List<PTGetPTStaticDataTypeForViewDto>> Get(PTGetPTStaticDataTypeInput input)
    {
        return await _ptStaticDataRepository.Get(input);
    }
```

REPOSITORY

```
public class PTStaticDataTypeRepository : PieceTrackerRepositoryBase<PTStaticDataType, long>, IPTStaticDataTypeRepository
{
    private readonly IActiveTransactionProvider _transactionProvider;
    public PTStaticDataTypeRepository(IDbContextProvider<PieceTrackerDbContext> dbContextProvider, IActiveTransactionProvider transactionProvider)
        : base(dbContextProvider)
    {
        _transactionProvider = transactionProvider;
    }


    public async Task<List<PTGetPTStaticDataTypeForViewDto>> Get(PTGetPTStaticDataTypeInput input)
    {
        var data = new List<PTGetPTStaticDataTypeForViewDto>();
        var cn = Context.Database.GetDbConnection();
        if (cn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            await cn.OpenAsync();
        using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "usp_GetPTStaticDataType";
            **cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;**
```

Answer (score 0):

The testing framework uses an in memory SQL Lite DB to pass thru the SQL commands.  So I created a workaround in my custom repository.

```
private DbConnection GetSqlConnection()
{
    const string TESTINGDB = "memory";
    const string PTCONNSTRING = "Server=(local); Database=PieceTrackerDb; Trusted_Connection=True;";
    var cn = Context.Database.GetDbConnection();
    if (cn.ConnectionString.Contains(TESTINGDB))
    {
        cn = new SqlConnection(PTCONNSTRING);
    }
    var logMsg = "PTStaticDataTypeRepository.Get Connection String = " + cn.ConnectionString;
    Console.WriteLine(logMsg);
    return cn;
}
```